# How to turn on zle?

Tags: cygwin, zsh, mintty

Having read the *zshzle* man page, I wanted to try out the `zle_highlight` parameter, and typed in my interactive zsh

```
zle_highlight=(blue bold)
```

with no visible effect. Digging further, I found that the command

```
zle
```

returns exit code **1**, and a `echo $ZLE_STATE` says ***zsh: ZLE_STATE: parameter not set***. I conclude from this, that *zle* is not turned on. My `TERM` variable contains *xterm-256color* and colouring **does** work; for instance, I can configure a coloured prompt. According to the man-page, I would say that under these conditions, *zle* should be turned on. What did I do wrong?

My environment is: Windows 10, Cygwin, running in a mintty terminal.

Comment: `ZLE_STATE` is only relevant when zle is active, not merely enabled. It'll only have a value when defining custom zle widgets.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The value you've given to `zle_highlight` makes no sense. It needs to know what should be coloured. And is the foreground or the background to be blue. Try something like:

```
zle_highlight=( default:fg=blue,bold)
```

`default` is used for the text entered at the prompt but other keys such as `region` and `paste` are possible.

Comment: Thank you! I now found that this is described in the section **CHARACTER HIGHLIGHTING** in the man-page. I missed that part before.